# Question about using Lagrange dual problem to determine the values of $\arg\min$

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

For instance we want to find the minimum value of $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n |x_i|$ subject to the constraints $x_i \geq 0$. Then the Lagrangian of this problem is

$$L (\mathbf{x},\mathbf{\lambda}) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n |x_i|-\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \lambda_ix_i$$

Using simple arguments we can find that the Lagrange dual function $g(\lambda)=0$ and furthermore we must have $-1\leq \lambda_i \leq 1$ for all $i$,this we have found the dual problem of the original problem.

However the form of this problem makes me a little bit worried. Also in this problem we cannot solve the variable $\lambda$ from the dual problem and then obtain the value of $x$ that minimizes the original expression, which is quite different from the case I have met before(such as some optimization problems of quadratic functions).

I wonder whether there are mistakes in my arguments, or that this is indeed the case?

Answer (score 1):

The dual function is $g(\lambda)=\inf_{x} \|x\|_1 - \lambda^T x$, where $\lambda \ge 0$.
I'm not sure I follow your concern, perhaps the following will help?

By choosing $x=0$ we see that $g(\lambda) \le 0$ for all $\lambda \ge 0$.

If any $\lambda_k >1$ then $g(\lambda) = -\infty$.

If and $\lambda_k =1$ then any $x_k \ge 0$ will have the same cost.

It is clear that $g$ is maximised when $\lambda_k \in [0,1]$ and the maximum value is zero.

The maximum value of zero is always attained with $x=0$, and if any $\lambda_k =1$ then one can choose any non negative value for the corresponding $x_k$.

Note in the above cases, I am working from an optimising $\lambda $ and determining the corresponding $x$ (which is not necessarily unique).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.what I feel confused about is that, now that we have derived the expression of $g$(the zero function in this case),we want to decide which $x$ minimizes the original function. The common approach is solving $\lambda$ for the dual problem and then use relationship between $\lambda$ and $x$(Obtained by, for example,KKT) to determine $x$. In the cases I met before, this $x$ automatically satisfies the constraints imposed on it, but in this case, it seems that in the final step of choosing $x$ we have to take into account of the constraint $x \geq 0$.

Comment: For example, in your approach, when $\lambda_k=0$ all $x_k$ will have the same cost.However, in this step we need to consider the original constraint $x \geq 0$, which itself does not appear as a constraint of the dual problem.

Comment: Thus, is it true that the value of $x$ and $\lambda$ suggested by the dual problem is not always valid in the original one?In view of this problem the answer is is, but when the $\lambda$ and $x$ obtained are unique, is there any garantee that the $x$ must satisfies the original constraints(otherwise we would get no solution)?

Comment: Hmm, let's see. The idea is that the $\lambda$ as such forces the $x$ to be feasible. So in the above we get $g(\lambda) = 0$. This means $0 \le \lambda_k \le 1$. If any of the $\lambda_k =1$ the corresponding $x_k$ (that solves $g(\lambda) = 0$) must be $x_k \ge 0$ and if the $\lambda_k \in [0,1)$ then we must have $x_k = 0$. This comes from solving $g(\lambda)=0$ for $x$ not from considerations of feasibililty.